# how can you create your own attr accessors with tumblr api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tumblr, attr-accessor

Can you create your own attr accessors with tumblr api?
For example, let's say I want to get likes and reblog notes separate.

Could I find a way to make some code similar to this:

```
attr_accessor :reblog_notes, :like_notes

puts client.posts["id"].like_notes
puts client.posts["id"].reblog_notes
```

I'm curious as to how limited we are with creating and experimenting with the tumblr api. Thank you for your time and consideration. :)

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/tumblr-api) exact gem?

Comment: i was using tumblr_client gem, but whichever works @KirillZhukov